# Obtaining json and convert it to array in angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I've done the angular2 quickstart and the tour of heroes tutorial from the angular site in order to get acquaintanced with it, and after getting it running I felt like the next step was adding a database connection using `nodejs` and `koa` to the tour of heroes app to add a little more scalability. I've followed https://github.com/mahalo1984/TourOfHeroesWithMongoDb this tutorial for the most part, changed the db from mongo to mysql and adapted what I needed.

I've upladed my code to https://github.com/nagarz/HeroEditor for the ones who want to see all the code.

I've got the database setup working and I get the query result json formatted, but when I try to pick it up with the getHeroes service which should convert send a promise to the template, I get this

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

I'm kinda new to JS, and I was getting most of it, and I was able to fix errors given the log, but this one is something I can't get past, this one. I'm not a JS/angular2 wizard, but from what I get the json is not being picked properly by the service and when it tries to convert it into an array and slice it to get X amount of elements from it, it gives the error. I've tried different stuff to get it working but no dice, so I figured I'd ask here hoping that someone better than me (not that hard, feelsbadman) can see what's the problem and point me to it so I can finish the whole setup.

This is the route I use to query the database

`router.get('/api/heroes', function* (){
    var rows = yield db.query("select * from heroes");
    this.body = { heroes: rows };
});`

When I enter the url `http://localhost:3333/api/heroes` in my browser I get the result in json like this

`{"heroes":[{"id":1,"hid":1,"name":"Saitama"},{"id":2,"hid":2,"name":"Genos"},{"id":3,"hid":3,"name":"Watchdog Man"},{"id":4,"hid":4,"name":"Metal BAt"},{"id":5,"hid":5,"name":"Puri Puri Prisoner"},{"id":6,"hid":10,"name":"Speed of sound, Sonic"},{"id":7,"hid":11,"name":"Tatsumaki"}]}`

And this is where I obtain the response and try to convert it into an array for processing the info in the app.

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    ...
    private getHeroesUrl = 'http://localhost:3333/api/heroes';
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    //this is the method in question
    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.getHeroesUrl).toPromise().then(response => response.json().data as Hero[]).catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

This is the `Hero` model class:

```
export class Hero {
    hid: number;
    name: string;
}
```

This is the class where method from the service is called, and the obtained array is sliced, and the point where I'm getting the Exception

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    heroes: Hero[] = [];
    ...
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 4));
    }
    ...
```

}

This is the full stacktrace of the exception:

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/components/dashboard.component.js:22:91)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:28)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6242:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:202:34)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:96:43)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:462:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6233:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:235:42)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47) TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/components/dashboard.component.js:22:91)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:28)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6242:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:202:34)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:96:43)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:462:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6233:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:235:42)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are expecting an array to be returned but the data is actually an Object. Try this

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.getHeroesUrl).toPromise().then(response => response.json().data.heroes as Hero[]).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

your hero array is nested under a 'heroes' key in a JSON data structure.

Comment: I already tried that, it doesn't work. It says that the response.json() is not defined, so it doesn't find it, There's something wrong in the way to obtain the json and for the love of me I can't see what's wrong, and in the tutorial I was following at github the code is the same, so I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: If you look in the network tab of your browser's developer console, do you see the request coming back with data? Is it a 200 response code? Often times when hitting a local server you need to set up the API to handle CORS.

Comment: The respons is a 200 OK code, I already found that problem and fixed it with the koa-cors packet.
This is the content of the response:
`{"heroes":[{"id":1,"hid":1,"name":"Saitama"},{"id":2,"hid":2,"name":"Genos"},{"id":3,"hid":3,"name":"Watchdog Man"},{"id":4,"hid":4,"name":"Metal BAt"},{"id":5,"hid":5,"name":"Puri Puri Prisoner"},{"id":6,"hid":10,"name":"Speed of sound, Sonic"},{"id":7,"hid":11,"name":"Tatsumaki"}]}`

Comment: Did you try removing the .data? so just

`.then(response => response.json().heroes)`

Comment: I did not try that, and that did it, you man have pretty keen eyes. Thanks for everything :D

Comment: No problem man! Note that it matches up with the key you're using here

`this.body = { heroes: rows };`

Answer (score 4):

The `in-memory-web-api` module has a breaking change:

> As of v0.5.0 (5 October 2017), the dataEncapsulation configuration
>   default changed from false to true. The HTTP response body holds the
>   data values directly rather than an object that encapsulates those
>   values, {data: ...}. This is a breaking change that affects almost all
>   existing apps!

So, in the example, change this:

```
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

to:

```
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Hero[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```